# linux + yum update - what this command covers?

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, patch-management, rhn

we have red-hat version 6.x machine,

I verified what are the missing security patches as the following:

```
 yum updateinfo list security available
 Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
 This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
 RHSA-2016:0073 security bind-libs-32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.6.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0073 security bind-utils-32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.6.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0428 security libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6_7.1.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0007 security nss-3.19.1-8.el6_7.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0007 security nss-sysinit-3.19.1-8.el6_7.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0007 security nss-tools-3.19.1-8.el6_7.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0370 security nss-util-3.19.1-5.el6_7.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0063 security ntp-4.2.6p5-5.el6_7.4.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0063 security ntpdate-4.2.6p5-5.el6_7.4.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0008 security openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.2.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0301 security openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4.x86_64
 RHSA-2016:0005 security rpcbind-0.2.0-11.el6_7.x86_64
 updateinfo list done
```

**I have two questions:**

when I run the following yum command:

```
yum update -y
```

dose this yum command will be installed all the missing security patch?? ( as I mentioned in the list )

when **yum update -y** completed to installed all patches ,

is it mean that my Linux red-hat machine version 6.x is fully updated with all patches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `yum -y update` will install all those security patches it found in your previous command

Comment: I have another question , what is the diff when installing from the RHN the errata patches to install it on the Linux machine by yum , is there are diff between the two approach ?

Comment: yum is set to pul those errata rpms.. so you don't need to do it by hand